# Flutter Equatable Class properties must all be final

Tags: class, flutter, dart

I'd like to know if this is something I can ignore.

I'm extending Equatable in order to compare objects, but the extended class requires my properties to be final (immutable, i get that). But, that stops me from being able to edit that object once I pass it into a widget. I can remove the final and it works just fine, I can then pass in an object into a widget, edit it, and then pass it back great (without creating a hundred variables).

So my question. Is this acceptable, will Equatable still work? If yes, then great it something they need to fix. If not, why not, what is my options to pass in and edit an object using a class that extends Equatable?

> Error : This class (or a class which this class inherits from) is
>   marked as '@immutable', but one or more of its instance fields are not
>   final:

```
class PriceItem extends Equatable {
  final String key; // I removed the final here

  PriceItem({
    this.key,
  });

  @override
  List<Object> get props => [
        key,
      ];
}
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

See equatable docs:

> Note: Equatable is designed to only work with immutable objects so all member variables must be final (This is not just a feature of Equatable - [overriding a hashCode with a mutable value can break hash-based collections](https://dart.dev/guides/language/effective-dart/design#avoid-defining-custom-equality-for-mutable-classes)).

If you think about it, there is no reason that you'll have two mutable objects that have the same key, because if only one of them changes - the fact that they have comparable keys is meaningless.

You might just define a method in PriceItem that accepts another PriceItem and checks for key equality.

Comment: That makes sense.